# Twitter using C# and .net 2.0

Tags: twitter, twitter-oauth

I need to create a web page that will allow my manager a way to post tweets to our twitter account.  I've looked at many APIs and they all seem to be for higher versions of the .net framework than 2.0 or are no longer working.  If someone could point me to an API or a way to connect to twitter using my username, password and Consumer key and secret to post a message so our followers can see I would appreciate it.

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Spring.NET Social extension for Twitter supports .NET 2.0 :

http://www.springframework.net/social-twitter/